# Debugging C++ Native Windows Phone 8 app

Tags: c++, debugging, c++11, exception

I am trying to figure out how to get to `0x0001556c` offset of my application. This is the error that came in apphub:

```
"Frame    Image                            Function               Offset        
0        kernelbase                       RaiseException         0x00000036    
1        msvcr110                         _CxxThrowException     0x0000005a    
2        windowsphone8program                                    0x0001556c"
```

A C++ exception is being thrown, but I need to see what the assembly looks like around it to figure out what exception is thrown

The `windowsphone8program` is a dll file, how would I be able to navigate to the `0x0001556c` offset? What tools can I use?

I've tried locating `0x0001556c` in my code but it's just `?? ??` in Visual Studio.

Is it possible to debug this error?

Comment: You need to know the base address `windowsphone8program` was loaded at.

Comment: @dauphic This information is not provided in the debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that there are any tools that will help you here, but I could be wrong.

I think your best choice is to create a sample application that loads your DLL. Once it's loaded, acquire the address it was loaded at, offset the address by `0x0001556C`, and use the functions provided by dbghelp (particularly [SymFromAddr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681323%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) to get the symbol matching the address.

You can retrieve the base address of the DLL either by breaking into the debugger and checking your Modules window, or by calling `GetModuleHandle` with your DLL's name and treating the return value as the base address.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. I opened the Modules Window as you suggested and found that the base address is `6BE60000`. I then added the offset (`0x0001556C`) and got to `6BE75558  bl          luabridge::LuaException::LuaException (6BE75E8Ch)` which is a LuaBridge lua exception Thanks!